# Excel Power Query - group by column - running total with a twist

Tags: excel

[Test Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwWxt.png)

Newbie, here to stackoverflow. The issue I'm having is that I would create a running total per month, based on what month it is. I wish to take the value in the column TOTAL_PER_MONTH and divide by the # of units in column Units if column Unit is 0. So for the above month = 12 and unit = 0 then 1170/2 would equal 585 in TOT column. For each other Unit in Unit column for each other Unit (1,2,3,4) would be adding the 585 to each of the TOTAL_PER_MONTH values.
Resulting TOT column I wish to have, would be as the following.

> | MONTH | UNIT | Units | TOTAL_PER_MONTH | SPLIT_UNIT_0 | TOT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12 | 0 | 2 | 1170 | 585 | 585 |
> | 12 | 1 | 2 | 565 | 585 | 585 + 565 = 1150 |
> | 12 | 2 | 2 | 494 | 585 | 585 + 494 = 1079 |
> | 12 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 585 | 585 + 1 = 586 |
> | 12 | 4 | 2 | 159 | 585 | 585 + 159 = 744 |
> | 01 | 0 | 2 | 1872 | 936 | 936 |
> | 01 | 1 | 2 | 771 | 936 | 771 + 936 = 1707 |
> | 01 | 2 | 2 | 438 | 936 | 438 + 936 = 1812 |
> | 01 | 4 | 2 | 682 | 936 | 682 + 936 = 1618 |
> | 01 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 936 | 1 + 936 = 937 |

I tried posting some I tried but couldn't get it to format properly...

Would appreciate any help someone can provide....

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since you chose to post your original data as a screenshot, which I could not copy/paste, I used your other table to do the calculations. But you should be able to adapt the method easily to your real data*

I use `List.Generate` to generate your modified `TOT` column, then add that list  as a column using the `Table.FromColumns` function.

But, we do this as a custom aggregation of a `Table.Group` function where we have grouped the data by Month

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table18"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"MONTH", Int64.Type}, {"UNIT", Int64.Type}, {"Units", Int64.Type}, {"TOTAL_PER_MONTH", Int64.Type}, {"SPLIT_UNIT_0", Int64.Type}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"MONTH"}, {
        {"TOT", (t)=>Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(t) & {
                List.Generate(
                    ()=>[rt=t[TOTAL_PER_MONTH]{0} / t[Units]{0}, idx=0],
                    each [idx] < Table.RowCount(t),
                    each [rt=t[TOTAL_PER_MONTH]{0} / t[Units]{0} +t[TOTAL_PER_MONTH]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                    each [rt])}, Table.ColumnNames(t) & {"TOT"})}
                    }),
    
    #"Expanded TOT" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "TOT", 
        {"UNIT", "Units", "TOTAL_PER_MONTH", "SPLIT_UNIT_0", "TOT"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded TOT",{
        {"UNIT", Int64.Type}, {"Units", Int64.Type}, 
        {"TOTAL_PER_MONTH", Int64.Type}, 
        {"SPLIT_UNIT_0", Int64.Type}, {"TOT", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

*Note that Line 8 in your example `438 + 936 = 1374` not `1812`*

*Also, you don't really need the `SPLIT_UNIT_0` column for this calculation, unless you need that column for other purposes in your data.*